# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, windows-10

My c# wpf app was running well on old windows 7 workstation. And it does on new windows 10 workstation i had to migrate my workplace programs.
Problems occur when i try to print some crystal reports on new machine.

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll

Additional information: Dokument nie został otwarty (Document wont open).

Program breaks on:
ReportDocument rpt2 = new ReportDocument()

I reainstalled crystal report runetime engines, .nets etc.
And i cant figure out what causes that COMException

Thx for any help

Comment: Is your C# app compiled for any CPU architecture? If yes, try to recompile it for 32bit only. Does your C# app run as normal process (under current users credentials) or as service? Crystal engine need full acess to temporary folder, whis may not be granted while running as service.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled 32 bit version of Crystal report engine.
I had to use cr engine in version 13.0.2000... This is an old project :)

Below there are older versions of crystal, if someone occur similiar problem in future
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-download-for-visual-studio/

Thx for comment

Comment: We are using CR engine 11.5, and our project is not that old :)